# chown via paramiko by username and not uid

Tags: python, paramiko

I need to run chown on a certain file on a remote server to change the owner (not the group). The paramiko chown command takes 3 arguments: path, gid, uid.

In my code, I have the username, not the uid. So this is my code:

```
#some code here
...
object_stat = sftp_client.stat(object_path)
sftp_client.chown(object_path, owner_username, int(object_stat.st_gid))
...
#more code
```

Is there a way to workaround this? If we can avoid using shell commands it is preferred.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use pexpect and then directly run chown command .It would like running cmd on ur own system.

Comment: @vks - thanks. Can pexpect "ride on" the paramiko connection? Or do I have to open a new connection?

Comment: no it makes its own connection.

Comment: You can get uids from usernames and usernames from uids via the `pwd` module. https://docs.python.org/2/library/pwd.html

Answer (score 0):

```
  import pexpect
  new_child=pexpect.spawn("ssh ....")
  new_child.expect("Password:")
  new_child.sendline(mypass)
  new_child.expect("$")#or whatever the bash symbol is 
  new_child.sendline("chown. ...")
  new_chile.expect("$")
```

if you want output use new_child.before

Comment: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/how-to-use-the-pexpect-module-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer from the far future for anyone looking this up. You can use the SFTP client to send arbitrary SSH commands, i.e.,

```
def sendCommand(sftp, *command, **kwargs):
  cmd = " ".join([str(c) for c in command])

  session = sftp.sock.get_transport().open_channel(kind = "session")

  try:
    session.exec_command(cmd)

    stdout = bytearray()
    stderr = bytearray()
    rc = 0 

    while True:
      if session.exit_status_ready():
        while True:
          data = session.recv(8192)
          if not data:
            break
          stdout.extend(data)
        while True:
          data = session.recv_stderr(8192)
          if not data:
            break
          stderr.extend(data)
        break

    rc = session.recv_exit_status()

    if rc != 0 and not kwargs.get("ignore_errors", False):
      raise ValueError("Command {0} failed with exit code {1}.\n{2}".format(" ".join(command), rc, stderr))
    else:
      try:
        return stdout.decode("UTF-8")
      except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return stdout
  finally:
    session.close()
```

Then, using this, we can use the channel to run `getent`. When ran against the `passwd` database, you'll get something like `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`. Index 2 is UID for the user, index 3 is GID for the user (note - not the GID for an arbitrary group name).

```
uid = sendCommand(client, "getent", "passwd", username).split(":")[2]
```

For groups, do the same but use the `group` database.

```
gid = sendCommand(client, "getent", "group", group).split(":")[2]
```

`getent` can be passed a UID or GID as well, which will let you do lookups in the reverse direction. Note I'm strictly speaking about POSIX hosts, YMMV with other systems.